# Open Embedded startup difficulties

Tags: linux, arm, openembedded

So, I am currently trying to get a hold on [Open Embedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Getting_started) to build for an i.MX53 platform, but i have some difficulties in understanding the main outline of the OE concept, as well as how the folder structure should be, gaining an upper view.

So, I was hoping someone could in a few words summarize why not just using the make command in the kernel root.

more importantly(for me ), i would like to know how the folder structure should be, having a [Oe-core](http://cgit.openembedded.org/cgit.cgi/openembedded-core/) and the [meta-fsl-arm](http://github.com/Freescale/meta-fsl-arm) layer built for an [i:MX53QSB](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=IMX53QSB).

Which file am I supposed to run with [bitbake](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/bitbake/) to get a custom image for my device?

Comment: Been waiting for some time now, with no answer.. I am digging into the matter and will hopefully produce an answer which I will post here...

Comment: I've been trying with OpenEmbedded-Core on Freescale i.MX28, but no success yet, as described in [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135129/cant-boot-basic-openembedded-core-on-freescale-i-mx28).

Answer (score 0):

you should start building some bitbake example recipes, if you hace success with this you should move forward to build your own images. look for the configuration scripts for angstrom, they will help you for setting up some things like architecture and deploy platform. After all these stuff you should put your custom image in your openembedded images folder and execute:

> bitbake my_image

Answer (score 0):

Start with [this link](http://crashcourse.ca/wiki/index.php/Poky) It is a comprehensive study of the Yocto Open Embedded project. Yocto is a ready-to-go subset that is known to work and is a good place to start.

[This link](http://crashcourse.ca/wiki/index.php/Poky_Directory_Hierarchy) shows you the directory hierarchy.